# Unable to upload SSL certificate to Azure with a Service Principal account

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-rm-template

I've created an ARM template that uploads an SSL certificate to Azure. I can run the ARM template from my local machine and it succeeds without any errors.

I then log into VSTS to set up a release template to perform the same task. I select the same template and provide the same parameters, but when I deploy the release it errors with a 401. The only information I can get by looking into the logs is that the request is denied because authorization failed.

I updated the permissions for the Service Principal account that VSTS is using to match my own (Owner, Contributor) of the resource group I'm deploying to and I get the same error. I then, temporarily, updated its permissions to Owner, Contributor of the entire subscription, and it still failed.

I'm beginning to suspect that this is an issue with Service Principal accounts in general, but I can't find any documentation to confirm or refute this claim.

Comment: Hvae you setup the service principal in the services section as a service endpoint? When you select the subscription to deploy to, it has "manage" on the right of it...

Comment: try with your regular account and see if that works? or try manually with service account and see if that works?

Comment: @EdwardRixon: Yes, that is how the service principal was created in the first place. ARM deployments in general with the service principal work just fine, the only time I encounter an error is when I try and upload an SSL certificate.

Comment: @4c74356b41: I just tried to run the template locally as the service principal account and I get the same error as when I run it on VSTS, so I've confirmed that it has to be something with the service principal account itself, just not sure what it is.